# Como lograr que al dar clic en una caja de una pila de 6 divs, se ubique encima y que la anterior ocupe su lugar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estoy con un problema de 6 divs apilados, solapados pero desplazados hacia abajo y hacia la derecha de tal modo que me permite dar clic a cada uno de éllos. Lo que quiero es que al dar clic en cualquiera de estos, se desplace al frente; pero que el div anterior se mueva a ocupar su lugar.

He probado con un script de JQuery, pero no logro conseguirlo.

Aqui está el codigo que he probado:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".ta").click(function () {
            $(this).css({"z-index":"100","left":"140","top":"140"});
            $(this).siblings().css({"z-index":"0","left":"","top":""});
        });
});
```

```css
#padre{
        border:solid 1px #2A1212;
        width: 550px;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: #D8E9F4;
        position: relative;
}
.ta{
        border:double 4px #2D2727;
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: 350px;
        height: 250px;
        position: absolute;
}
#tab1{
        background-color: #F40C0C;
        left: 20px;
        top: 20px;
        z-index: 1;
}
#tab2{
        background-color: #EC0CF4;
        left: 40px;
        top: 40px;
        z-index: 2;
}
#tab3{
        background-color: #2D0CF4;
        left: 60px;
        top: 60px;
        z-index: 3;
}
#tab4{
        background-color: #0CF1F4;
        left: 80px;
        top: 80px;
        z-index: 4;
}
#tab5{
        background-color: #0CF43D;
        left: 100px;
        top: 100px;
        z-index: 5;
}
#tab6{
        background-color: #F1F40C;
        left: 120px;
        top: 120px;
        z-index: 6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="padre">
        <div id="tab1" class="ta"></div>
        <div id="tab2" class="ta"></div>
        <div id="tab3" class="ta"></div>
        <div id="tab4" class="ta"></div>
        <div id="tab5" class="ta"></div>
        <div id="tab6" class="ta"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En CSS usa ID solo para asignar color, clase para el resto de atributos y, para las posiciones, usa [div:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), asignando ubicación de acuerdo a la posición del elemento dentro de *#padre* (1 a 6).

Cuando se hace clic en uno de los elementos muévelo al frente, aprovechando que `jQuery(padre).append(elemento)` o `Node.appendChild(elemento)` simplemente mueven el elemento al final del contenedor, aplicando automáticamente las reglas CSS para reubicar todos los divs:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ta").click(function () {
        // Posición del elemento actual (0 a 5)
        let index = $(this).index();
        // Mover solo si no está ya al frente
        if(index < 5) {
            // Traer el elemento del frente (5)
            // a la posición del elemento que recibió el clic
            $(".ta").eq(5).insertBefore($(this));
            // Enviar elemento al frente
            $("#padre").append($(this));
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#padre{
        border:solid 1px #2A1212;
        width: 550px;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: #D8E9F4;
        position: relative;
}
#padre div:nth-child(1) {
        left: 20px;
        top: 20px;
        z-index: 1;
}
#padre div:nth-child(2) {
        left: 40px;
        top: 40px;
        z-index: 2;
}
#padre div:nth-child(3) {
        left: 60px;
        top: 60px;
        z-index: 3;
}
#padre div:nth-child(4) {
        left: 80px;
        top: 80px;
        z-index: 4;
}
#padre div:nth-child(5) {
        left: 100px;
        top: 100px;
        z-index: 5;
}
#padre div:nth-child(6) {
        left: 120px;
        top: 120px;
        z-index: 6;
}
.ta{
        border:double 4px #2D2727;
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: 350px;
        height: 250px;
        position: absolute;
}
#tab1{
        background-color: #F40C0C;
}
#tab2{
        background-color: #EC0CF4;
}
#tab3{
        background-color: #2D0CF4;
}
#tab4{
        background-color: #0CF1F4;
}
#tab5{
        background-color: #0CF43D;
}
#tab6{
        background-color: #F1F40C;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="padre">
        <div id="tab1" class="ta"></div>
        <div id="tab2" class="ta"></div>
        <div id="tab3" class="ta"></div>
        <div id="tab4" class="ta"></div>
        <div id="tab5" class="ta"></div>
        <div id="tab6" class="ta"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Triby](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/54039/triby/)

Comment: @Jorge, ¡ese soy yo!, ¿para qué soy bueno?

Comment: **@Triby   Su respuesta a mi pregunta es Positiva. Las cajas se ubican en la posicion requerida. Me gusta el código por ser muy simple. Mi pregunta era(https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/377533/como-lograr-que-al-dar-clic-en-una-caja-de-una-pila-de-6-divs-se-ubique-encima)**[Triby](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/54039/triby/)

Comment: Perfecto, si te funcionó, no olvides marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: ya la acepté. Que más debo hacer?

Comment: @Jorge, nada más, eso es todo. ¡Gracias!